# Spring with JPA - fail if no transactional context defined

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, transactions, spring-transactions

I want to require that every JPA call occurs inside @Transactional context and if I forgot about that annotation, JPA should throw an exception instead of creating implicit transaction for each call. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a part of your question that is easier to answer "JPA should throw an exception instead of creating implicit transaction for each call". You're aware of the [transaction propagation levels](http://techannotation.wordpress.com/2012/05/29/5-minutes-with-jpa-transaction/)

```
MANDATORY
          Support a current transaction, throw an exception if none exists.
NESTED
          Execute within a nested transaction if a current transaction exists, behave like PROPAGATION_REQUIRED else.
NEVER
          Execute non-transactionally, throw an exception if a transaction exists.
NOT_SUPPORTED
          Execute non-transactionally, suspend the current transaction if one exists.
REQUIRED
          Support a current transaction, create a new one if none exists.
REQUIRES_NEW
          Create a new transaction, suspend the current transaction if one exists.
SUPPORTS
          Support a current transaction, execute non-transactionally if none exists.
```

*REQUIRED* is default, and the semantic you search for fits the *MANDATORY*. This would be easily configurable by using `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.MANDATORY)` on a class level, for all the beans you would like to exhibit this behaviour (DAO layer beans being the usual suspects, as they should not be the transaction owners anyway, rather always execute in a larger context).

The tricky part to answer is how to enforce it when you actually omit the @Transactional. Omitting the annotation doesn't guarantee anything, it could be that the transaction semantic is added via [AOP](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative). Or that the class doesn't manage transactions at all.

I would definitely advise to keep the *REQUIRED* as default and fine tune the propagation level as you find fitting by always declaring @Transactional with the proper propagation level.

However, to try to answer the ommitting bit, you can change also the default propagation level globally, in spring configuration, something like

```
<tx:advice id="txAdvice">
     <tx:attributes>
         <tx:method name="*" propagation="MANDATORY"/>
     </tx:attributes>
 </tx:advice>
```

And by doing this you would effectively flip the coin, and get an exception for all the methods that you didn't mark with `@Transactional(propagation = PROPAGATION.REQUIRED);`

Comment: Is it possible to apply that tx:advice specifically to EntityManager interface that's injected with @PersistenceContext annotation?

Comment: tx:advice advises the TransactionManager, and you can apply it to a specific TransactionManager. Later on you can join a PersistenceContext to transactions created with that specific manager, it should get you where you want. Read the 12.5.4 Configuring different transactional semantics for different beans from http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative. From what I understand it should be a way for you